# Re-using data pulled from a table without connecting to table again

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The Code below works perfectly but i need to re-use the four records(in this case) that are pulled from the database again without connecting to the MySQL again

see the code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
<li class="active"><a href="#000" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-new-tab2"></i> Featured</a></li>

<?php $cattid = $_GET['ListingID'];?>
<?php try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
 $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");// Sets encoding UTF-8
 $sql = "select * from $TableCatSub where cat_area_id='$cattid'" ;
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if($result !== false) {
 $cols = $result->columnCount();
 foreach($result as $row) {
?>
   <li>Title: <?php echo $row['cat_sub_area_title'];?></li>
<?php
 } 
 }
 $conn = null;
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
 }
?>              
</ul>
```

### This would be my results

1- Title:alpha

2 -Title:beta

3 - Title:charlie

4 - Title:delta

(1) My question is......

How do i assign a value to each of those four(or six or 8) results so that i can use them again in this manner IE....

```
<?php 
&SomeVariable1 = "alpha"
&SomeVariable2 = "beta"
&SomeVariable3 = "charlie"
&SomeVariable4 = "delta"
?>
```

So that i can use a value on my page like this.

```
 <?php echo &SomeVariable1 ;?>
```

I hope this is understandable...
(Ps... i am not a programmer and do not know the language at all.. what i have achieved to date has been by copying and pasting from forums. But from what i have read on the Internet i think those values need to be assign through arrays or something ?

Thank you

Comment: They are already assigned in an array: echo $result[0]['cat_sub_area_title']; echo $result[1]['cat_sub_area_title']; etc

Comment: Preserve your data in an array and use that array elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 1):

You still have the results available to you in your `$result` array. If you need to access them you can bind each result to a variable. E.g. `$alpha = $result['alpha']`

Answer (score 0):

You already have those variables (its in the `$result` array) and you can re-use it.
For example -

```
$var1 = $result['alpha'];
$var2 = $result['beta'];
$var3 = $result['charlie'];
$var4 = $result['delta'];
```

Comment: Thank you... Every place i try this code or the other suggestions i get this error ! - ((Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in......))